# ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que al leer cada serie no tenga que abrir cada vez la variable $url con la funcion fopen?

Tags: php, array, csv, highcharts, fopen

```
  series: [{
            name: 'Registros validados',
            data: [<?php 
            $numeros = array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0");
            if (($handle = fopen("$url2", "r")) !== FALSE) {
                while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
                    if ($data[2] == '' OR !in_array($data[2][0], $numeros)){
                        $data[2] = 'null';
                    }
                    print_r($data[2].",");
                }
                    fclose($handle);
            }?>]
        }, 
        {
            name: 'Registros preliminares',
            data: [<?php 
                $numeros = array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0");
                if (($handle = fopen("$url2", "r")) !== FALSE) {
                    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
                        if ($data[3] == '' OR !in_array($data[3][0], $numeros)){
                            $data[3] = 'null';
                        }
                        print_r($data[3].",");
                    }
                    fclose($handle);
                }?>]
        }, 
        {
            name: 'Registros no validados',
            data: [<?php 
                    $numeros = array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0");
                    if (($handle = fopen("$url2", "r")) !== FALSE) {
                    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
                        if ($data[4] == '' OR !in_array($data[4][0], $numeros)){
                            $data[4] = 'null';
                        }
                        print_r($data[4].",");
                    }
                    fclose($handle);}?>]
        }]
```

Comment: No entiendo tu código. ¿Esto es un array o un JSON con código PHP dentro? ¿Qué es lo que pretendes hacer exactamente con esto?

Comment: @A.Cedano Son series de datos de Highcharts, que abren contenido csv que están en una url y los entrega en array, todo lo anterior vía php.

Comment: `$mVariabe = fopen("$url2", "r");` y luego el los if evaluas a $mVariabe

Comment: De `Highcharts` no tengo ni idea, pero, ¿eso no trabajaría mejor con datos directamente que con código PHP? Así la lógica se implementa en PHP y alimentas a `Highcharts` solamente con los datos. No sé, es que me parece raro eso de tener código para pasárselo a otra herramienta.

Comment: @A.Cedano Si, pero los datos los extraigo de un servidor externo a mi, a través de un formulario según la fecha que solicita el usuario.

Comment: No sabría que decirte, me parece muy raro que el servidor no te proporcione alguna forma de leer los datos, como hace las API o los WS y que tengas que enviarle código PHP para que se ejecute. Y no sé a nivel de seguridad para ese servidor. Supongamos que un hacker utiliza tu serie y mete todo tipo de código dañino ¿eso se manda a ese servidor y se ejecuta? Me parece muy extraño todo.